# Calling a JSON based ASP.NET web-service from an Android phone

Tags: java, android, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I have two api methods and both of them are working perfect with ajax jquery calling but when I am calling these two method from android Http code, 1st method is working perfect and the other 2nd is not working

1st Method's example from calling jquery

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'websiteaddress/Accounts/Login?username=test&password=test',
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { alert(success);},
    error: function (reponse) { alert(reponse);}
});
```

2nd Method's example from calling jquery

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'websiteaddress/Accounts/Login',
    data: '{username: "test" , password: "test" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { alert(success);},
    error: function (reponse) { alert(reponse);}
});
```

Actually my question is related to android but I shared the jquery calling because it's code size is less than android :)

There is the main difference in both calling is 1st one sending data with URL and second one is with body.

Hope you understand my problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
I will share the android code, If needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lolx I found the answer as well :), may be my way of asking question is not correct because I know there are lots of genius developers on stackoverflow ;) who can answer any programming related questions.

solutions is very simple.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("username", "test");
data.put("password", "password");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
// Making the call.
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Well I was using other code, example below.

```
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the quotes in the data parameters, like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'websiteaddress/Accounts/Login',
 data: {username: "test" , password: "test" },
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) { alert(success);},
 error: function (reponse) { alert(reponse);}});
```

Hope helps!

Comment: Did you read till end of the question :) ? I am asking for android code which will take parameters not in URL or Querystring